# Use negative indent for my references in a scientific paper

Tags: formatting, cross-referencing, indentation, two-column, paper

I'm trying to use negative indent in my reference, to make them more clear. Like in this image:

[image: Negative indent in references]

When I use `\setlength{\parindent}{-1em}` in a paragraph, the results don't respect the original format of my paper, using the space between the columns:

[image]

How can I make everything in the paragraph, except for the first line, to be "indented" to the right, but inside the limits of the columns. Thank you and sorry for the confusing question.

Comment: Note when you do not provide any code so we can see what exaclt were are dealing with, you are very unlikely to get any help.

Comment: A solution depends extremely on how you are making your references. Currently we even do not know, if you use a manually build `thebibliography` environment, use BibTeX or `biblatex` and which style or anything else. So please see: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography

Comment: Looks like you tried something. So I suggest to take that piece of code, rework it via this checklist https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that/10137#10137 and add your (nice) code to your question, which focuses just on the indent problem. I'm quite sure, you'll get very qualified answers soon. "Code is our fuel", so to say :)

Answer (score 3):

> How can I make everything in the paragraph, except for the first line, to be "indented" to the right, but inside the limits of the columns?

You don't want negative indentation of the first line; rather, you want *hanging indentation* of the paragraph, starting with the 2nd line.

Take a look at the [hanging](https://ctan.org/pkg/hanging) package (to be loaded in the preamble) and its `hangparas` environment. E.g.,

```
...
\begin{hangparas}{1em}{1}
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
...
\end{thebibliography}
\end{hangparas}
...
```